# Number of ways to divide N different points into k groups

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I'm trying to calculate the following. Given N different points in 2D space, and $1 \leq K \leq N $

a) The number of possibilities, to divide the points into K groups, without importance of the group numbers.

b)The number of possibilities, to divide the points into K groups, with importance of the group numbers.

Empty groups are not allowed.

Thx for the help :)

Cheers

Comment: define importance of the group numbers and define group. Are you looking for Stirling numbers of the second kind?

Comment: Example: If I had the following set {1,2,3} and K=2: then the possibilities are:{{1,2}, {3}},  {{1}, {2,3}},  {{1,3}, {2}} 
and for a) the answer will be  3
but for b) the answer will be 6 since {{1}, {2,3}} and {{2,3},{1}} are considered different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for:
a) [Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind)
b) a)$\times k!.$ This are related to [Fubini numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_Bell_number). Notice that the $k!$ what it does is permutes the "group numbers".

Comment: thx ! I didn't know that this specific problem had a page of it's own haha, good to know :)

Comment: You are welcome @SammyApsel